# TypeError:'int' object is not subscriptable

Tags: python-3.x, typeerror

I am trying to make function that goes through a 2d list and counts how many birhts happened on any unique value on the specified column and then it loads it into a dictionary.

data: list of lists, column: index number of column

I get the `'int' object is not subscriptable` and i lookedet at similar question but nothing seems to work. I saw casting the object to int or str but it did not work

```
def calc_counts(data, column):
    calc_dict = {}
    for item in data:
        coundted_column = item[column]
        births = item[4]
        if item in calc_dict:
            calc_dict[coundted_column] = calc_dict[coundted_column] + births
        else:
            calc_dict[coundted_column] = births
     return calc_dict
```

Comment: You get the error at which line? If you give an example for `data`, we can help you better. Most probably `item` is an integer.

Answer (score 0):

i had figured it out. I had to mistakes actually. My argument for the list parameter was in the wrong format and the

```
if item in calc_dict:
```

should be

```
if coundted_column in calc_dict:
```